# How is Poloniex keeping track of their user's Monero balances when they do not use any Payment ID's?

Tags: address, balance, wallet, poloniex, block-scanning

When using poloniex, they issue a monero address to each user without the payment id's. How are they scanning so many user's monero private keys at once? I can't imagine them loading 1000s of wallet files one after another to scan the monero blockchain for an updated balance for each user. This is something I wanted to figure out but I never did in my own application that has many xmr private keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last I was aware, Poloniex issues users with a Monero *integrated address*, which embeds a payment ID in the address. You can easily verify this by the address length - integrated addresses are 106 hex digits long.

As the Monero community has already signalled that payment IDs are being deprecated, subaddresses should be used instead moving forwards.

Comment: you are correct... didn't realize this. im surprised other exchanges didn't adopt this approach. seems like a no brainer to reduce support issues for those leaving payment id's out.